# How to "run" OSGi fragments on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, osgi, fragment

I want to integrate some existing OSGi bundles and fragments in a servlet and run it on Tomcat 7. Following this tutorial http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-osgi3.html I managed to run the bundles on the server.
I read, that fragments have no life-cycle, so I assumed, I just have to run the bundle and the fragments are found automatically. Nevertheless, when the bundle is started on the server, it seems as if the OSGi fragments are not found. Calling "ss" on the OSGi console, I can see that my bundle is active. The fragment has the status "INSTALLED".

```
31  ACTIVE      myBundle
34  INSTALLED   myFragment
```

Since the integration of the fragment in the bundle worked, when I run it in Eclipse (as OSGi platfrom), I assume, that the Manifest.MF files are correct. Is this assumption correct?

Or is there another point I missed? Do I need to "start" the fragment somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: This project starts a OSGi-Container in a Tomcat10. https://github.com/enexusde/Karaf-Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer here:
[How do I ensure my OSGi fragments get installed before the host bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383038/how-do-i-ensure-my-osgi-fragments-get-installed-before-the-host-bundle?rq=1)

Citation: "One of the most common errors people make in OSGi is trying to start each bundle immediately after it is installed. You must not do this, i.e. you should not start any bundle until after you have installed all bundles that you intend to run."

Comment: Whoever said that is a genius ;-)

Comment: He definitely is. Thanks Neil :)